# ssh port forwarding, netcat test not working

Tags: openssh, ssh-tunnel

I have two machines, laptop and oracle.

This is a session:

TERMINAL 1 (starts a netcat on remote machine)

```
Laptop $ ssh -p 6789  zx@$ORCL_H -i ~/.ssh/identities/oracle/nixos/zx.priv.key  

Oracle $ nc -l 7777
```

TERMINAL 2 (starts a remote port forwarding)

```
Laptop $ ssh -p 6789 -L 9999:$ORCL_H:7777 zx@$ORCL_H -i ~/.ssh/identities/oracle/nixos/zx.priv.key
```

TERMINAL 3 (tries to connect to netcat server but via local port on laptop)

```
Laptop $ nc localhost 9999
```

--

ORCL_H is set correctly in both T1 and T2

However, when I try to type something in either netcat sessions, I see nothing. What am I doing wrong?

I've turned GatewayPorts yes on the remote machine.

I should note that the exact sequence of command but with another host (not oracle) works as expected

Answer (score 0):

Check if you do have `AllowTcpForwarding yes` in your sshd config in the Oracle machine.

EDIT: It should not be caused by packets silently dropped by firewall as incorrectly suggested in this post before. If you are able to connect there by SSH, the forwarded traffic should be indistinguishable.

Comment: So that's what I don't understand (re the firewall part)-- Isn't all the traffic going through ssh? Where would firewall come into picture?

Re: AllowTcpForwarding-- it seems that yes is the default option and my sshd_config doesn't override it. 

In fact, both the machine where I succeed, and the machine where I fail, have exact same sshd config (I use nixos on both with same configuration for services)

Comment: You are right, the bit with firewall does not make sense, removing...